# Talend ESB : How to call one route from another route?

Tags: apache-camel, esb, talend

In Talend ESB, I am troubled to figure out how to call another route from one route.

I have done quite a bit of search and found exactly the same question asked by someone else but it doesn't have any answer. So I thought It might be a good idea to post a question here. :)

Here's the link of the question:

https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=32416

Would be really appreciated if anyone could help!

Thanks

Comment: In Camel, you would use a to() in route1, naming route2 as your destination.Or, is there something more Talend-specific you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Hmm, I understand the idea, but I am not sure how to this in talend. Any idea how i can achieve this in Talend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use cDirectVM and cSEDA. cDirectVM will send the exchange to another cDirectVM endpoint with the same name and block the first route until the second finish (synchronous). cSEDA is asynchronous, the first route will not wait for the second route to process the exchange.

Documentation for cDirectVM : https://help.talend.com/display/TalendESBMediationComponentsReferenceGuide60EN/cDirectVM

Be aware that this is not testable in studio, when you start 2 routes inside the studio, they will run in separate JVM and thus they will not see each other and cDirectVM will fail. But if you launch the 2 routes on the Talend runtime, cDirectVM will work between the 2 routes.

Answer (score 1):

One other solution is to use JMS (ActiveMQ is seeded with Talend and works fine). 
The last enndpoint of your first route will be a cJMS that sends the message body to the MQ Broker, then this queue will be the entry of your 2nd route.

Of you could do the same with file endpoints as well, or CXF (webservices) too.